# Is it possible to use iphone as an usb or bluetooth webcam on imac?

Tags: iphone, imac, usb, bluetooth, webcam

I have found many webcam apps, but all of them send the video signal through wifi, and this is not an option for me, because I need to use the phone hotspot at the same time I need to use it as a webcam. Is there a way to use the phone as webcam either through bluetooth, or usb?

Answer (score 2):

This is a youtube tutorial to build the apps ‍♂️

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-BBHiyLS1k

Comment: If someone knows an android version for mac or something similar please let me know

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant

Comment: Do I really have to set up the entire app compilation environment for this? The app should be available somewhere.

Comment: As I have read there are other solutions  4 streaming but those have lag imput. So if you want a real webcam 4 conferences it seems like

Comment: This is also not a solution for me. I need to be able to choose the phone as webcam in other apps, not just record what it sees through quicktime.